# Google Calendar v3 api Adding ExtendedProperties

Tags: google-calendar-api

Using the .net api I am adding a new event to Google and it is working fine until I add  ExtendedProperties.

I have tried this and I get an error "Object not set to an instance of an object" because ExtendedProperties is nothing.

```
myevent.ExtendedProperties.Shared.Add("MyKey", "MyValue")
```

So I tried this and got the same error because Shared is nothing.

```
Dim ep As New Data.Event.ExtendedPropertiesData
ep.Shared.Add("MyKey", "MyValue")
```

Seems that Shared is "Nothing" and nothing I do adds a new Shared. How do I add a new Shared ExtendedProperties if the Add method doesn't work?

I see plenty of samples on how to read ExtendedProperties and that seems to work fine. I also see plenty of samples on how to add Events. Does anyone know how to add an Event with ExtendedProperties?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found the solution:

```
Dim EP As New Data.Event.ExtendedPropertiesData()
EP.Shared = New System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, String)
EP.Shared.Add("MyKey", "MyValue")
myevent.ExtendedProperties = EP
```

Hope, it helps

Comment: Good answer and it works for the framework specified. Saved me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Inorder to set `Extended Properties`, you will have to use

```
myevent.ExtendedProperties.setShared(java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String> shared);
```

then use

```
myevent.ExtendedProperties.set("MyKey", "MyValue");
```

Here is the [link](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/calendar/model/Event.ExtendedProperties.html) for the documentation.